# Landscape Orientation: Change imageview src (using Picasso)

Tags: android, imageview, orientation, picasso, landscape

I am using a custom array adapter and displaying an image and some text within each row (JSON from a movie database API). When I change the orientation of the device, the list is loaded again and everything is displayed correctly, even though I have not specified a landscape orientation anywhere in the code. So far, great!

My problem is that in the **landscape orientation** I would like to **only change the image** that I am loading (using Picasso since it is an image URL). I want everything else to remain as is.

How can I achieve the same? Does Picasso itself have a function which could take care of such an issue?

Let me know if some code is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this piece of code:

```
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int rotation = display.getRotation();
    if (rotation != 0) {
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(your_url).into(your_imageview);
    }
```

It detects if there's a screen rotation, the display.getRotation returns an int (that equals 0 if there isn't any rotation), from there you can use Picasso to change your imageview.

Cheers,

Comment: Worked! Thanks. :)

Comment: Glad I could help... Anytime :D

Answer (score 1):

You should detect when your device change orientation
Then you should update the list datasource base on orientation and `notifyDataSetChanged`

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // change all image path in listdata to landscape path

        // for example
        // for (Item item : listData) {
        //     item.setDisplayImagePath(landscapePath);
        // } 
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        // change all image path in listdata to portrait path
    }

    youListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

Hope this help